# How to show image in datatable Angular 4 from API

Tags: angular

I want show the image in datatable, the data is from API. I Already get the url image but the image was not found. Maybe i have wrong syntax or another in html.

**This is my component.html**

```
<table class="table table-striped" [mfData]="roomLayouts | dataNameFilter : filterQuery" #mf="mfDataTable"
        [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage" [(mfSortBy)]="sortBy" [(mfSortOrder)]="sortOrder">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 10%">
              <mfDefaultSorter by="code">{{ 'Code' | translate }}</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 10%">
              <mfDefaultSorter by="name">{{ 'Name' | translate }}</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 10%">
              <mfDefaultSorter by="description">{{ 'FileName' | translate }}</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 10%">
              <mfDefaultSorter>Image</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 10%">
              {{ 'Action' | translate }}
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let rLayout of mf.data">
            <td>{{rLayout.code}}</td>
            <td>{{rLayout.name}}</td>
            <td>{{rLayout.fileName}}</td>
            <td><img [src]="rLayout.url" /> </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning ">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp; {{ 'Edit' | translate }}</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>&nbsp; {{ 'Delete' | translate }}</button>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
              <mfBootstrapPaginator [rowsOnPageSet]="[5,10,15]"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
```

**This is the output JSON what i get :**

[image]

Anyone have a solutions?

Comment: there is no <image> tag

Comment: @TM if you nend to show image in datatable add image tag and provide `[src]="url"`.

Comment: Insted of `<td><img [src]="rLayout.url" /> </td>` can you try as `<td><img src="{{rLayout.url}}" /> </td>`

Comment: @Sachi.Dila i already try but error

Comment: @Abhishek image tag is <img> right?

Comment: Code is clean, may be check with your image URL

Comment: Try with `{{ rLayout | json }}` to check what exactly you're getting in the rLayout Object. Looks like it doesn't have a `url` field. Update the OP with that response. It will help others figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @SiddAjmera you can check in my issues again, i have add output json

Comment: Are you sure that this image file exists?

Comment: Ahh. There's your issue. I don't think the image is going to get served up locally like this. To confirm this, you can copy the URL, open a new tab, paste the url in there and check. I don't think it will load up in there.

Comment: @TM image is exist in your location project folder name is `image`?

Comment: @SiddAjmera yeah i already try to copy url to browser and not load it, so the solution i must make server site to save & load the image? or you have another solution sir?

Comment: Are you using an express server on your local?

Comment: SQL server Object Explorer sir, with using framework .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: @TM save images is  your assets folder and image name similar as you get from API and `i.e: <img src="../../../../assets/icon/{{id}}.png">` like this.